# MySQL/MariaDB: Comparing performance between two queries

Tags: mysql, performance, explain, query-performance

I am trying to compare the performance between two queries which give otherwise the same results.

The idea is that I want to compare using Windowing Functions available to newer versions to faking them with subqueries in older versions.

Here are the two queries:

```
select
    *,
    sum(total) over (order by id) as running,
    sum(total) over (partition by ordered) as daily,
    sum(total) over (partition by ordered order by id) as daily_running
from sales
order by id;

select
    *,
    (select sum(total) from sales s where s.id<=sales.id) as fake_running,
    (select sum(total) from sales s where s.ordered=sales.ordered) as fake_daily,
    (select sum(total) from sales s where s.ordered=sales.ordered and s.id<=sales.id) as fake_daily_running
from sales
order by id;
```

The results are identical.

I know that I can use `EXPLAIN`, but (a) I’m unclear how to interpret the results, and (b) I can’t see how to get a direct comparison between the two.

Microsoft SQL Management Studio has a tool which displays shows the estimated execution plan, and, most importantly, the cost of each query relative to the whole.

How can I get details on how the performance of the two queries would compare?

Comment: You can compare the performance in practice only. On the real array of data. EXPLAIN will not help - it is used to optimize the single query, and all its data is relative, not absolute. PS. The change in source data (and/or its statistic) may fully change the EXPLAIN result for the same query...

Comment: The explain uses the same information as the query optimizer. While it is far from perfect it is often good enough, PROVIDED that the statistics are up-to-date and that the data is production-like and usually it is acceptable to run EXPLAIN in production. With outdated statistics and/or unrealistic data a practical test is just as bad. Start with the explain, which is cheap and easy to obtain; then by all means measure just in case.

Comment: Well, let's see the `EXPLAINs`, maybe we can help.  As for running timings -- be sure to have enough data, and for the data to realistic.

Comment: `SUM(...) OVER (ORDER BY ..)` does not make sense.  wouldn't it be the same to simply do `SUM(...)`?

Comment: Another metric:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Answer (score 3):

You should use `EXPLAIN`, or by all means test with realistic data. Microsoft's tool is nice, but it is basically the same thing under the hood. The classic explain syntax (`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`) does not include cost, but it does include the estimated number of rows for each step. Better, you can use JSON to get more details:

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...
```

This will return a JSON document that includes `query_cost`. You don't get a fancy graph, but you can compare the estimated cost. Good luck!